# On a series representation for a continuous 6j symbol integral: $\large{\int} \small\left\{ \begin{matrix} x&x&x \\ x&x&x \\ \end{matrix}\right \}dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I know this looks like a silly question, but please see the motivation.

$\large\text{Goal Integral:}$

Let me introduce the [**Racah/Wigner 6j symbols**](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/SixJSymbol/02/) which are defined discretely because of a $\text{PhysicalQ}(\{j_1,j_2,j_3\},\{j_4,j_5,j_6\})$ function. Let’s use ignore that restriction in the **bolded link** to analytically extend the domain. The link also has a few definitions in terms of regularized hypergeometric functions and factorials, also seen in the link. What would happen if we tried to make the inputs [central](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBetaFunction.html) and integrate using this new definition?. Here I integrate term by term:

$$\int  \left\{ \begin{matrix}
    x&x&x \\
    x&x&x \\
   \end{matrix}\right \}dx=\int \frac{(-1)^{4x} x!^6}{(3x+1)!^2}\sum_{n=0}^x\frac{(-1)^n(4x-n+1)!}{n!^3(x-n)!^4}dx=\pi\int\frac{\csc(4\pi x) x!^6}{(-1)^{4x}(3x+1)!^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x-n)!^4n!^3(n-4x-2)!}\mathop=\pi\int \frac{\csc(4\pi x)x!^2\,_4\mathrm {\tilde  F_3}(-x,-x,-x,-x,-4x-1,1,1,1)}{(3x+1)!^2}dx= \pi\int \frac{\csc(4\pi x)x!^2\,_4\text F_3(-x,-x,-x,-x,-4x-1,1,1,1)}{(3x+1)!^2(-4x-1)!}dx=\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!^3}\int\frac{\csc(4\pi x) x!^6}{(-1)^{4x} (3x+1)!^2 (x-n)!^4(n-4x-2)!}dx$$

This is the source for the [**main series representation ignoring the integer restriction**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=wigner6j&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Wigner6JCalculator%22%2C+%22j6%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22wigner6j%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Wigner6JCalculator%22%2C+%22j1%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Wigner6JCalculator%22%2C+%22j2%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Wigner6JCalculator%22%2C+%22j3%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Wigner6JCalculator%22%2C+%22j4%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Wigner6JCalculator%22%2C+%22j5%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22).

$\large\text{Motivaton:}$

I am looking for a series representation solution for the integral for any non-degenerate interval of convergence. I also know that we are integrating a factorial, but you actually can integrate a factorial using the [2 argument Lambda function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambdaFunction.html) and [Euler-Mascheroni Integrals $I_n$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniIntegrals.html). Here is also a gamma function integral for variety or which I am sure about the interval of convergence

$$\int_0^y x! dx=λ(1,y),\int Γ(x)dx=C-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n I_{n-1} (x-1)^n}{n!}=C+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac {d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} Γ(x)\right)_{x=1}\ (x-1)^n}{n!}$$

Here is the closed form of the central [Wigner Coefficients /Racah 3j Symbol](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ThreeJSymbol/02/) assuming an analytic continuation of the function without the $\text{PhysicalQ}(\{j_1,j_2,j_3\},\{j_4,j_5,j_6\})$ function constraint also seen in the link:

$$\int \left( \begin{matrix}
    x&x&x \\
    x&x&x \\
   \end{matrix}\right ) dx=\int(-1)^{2x}dx=C+\frac{i(-1)^{2x}}{2\pi}$$

The same goes for the [Clebsh-Gordon Coefficients](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ClebschGordan/). If we ignore the $\text{PhysicalQ}(\{j_1,j_2,j_3\},\{j_4,j_5,j_6\})$ restriction in the link, then we get an analytic continuation. Let’s make the function central by making all arguments equal to one another using the [Incomplete Gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) for $x\ne \frac12$:

$$\int \langle x\,x\,x\,x|x\,x\,x\,x\rangle dx=\int (-1)^{3x} \sqrt{2x+1}dx=\frac{(1+i)Γ\left(\frac32,-3i\pi \left(x-\frac12\right)\right)}{(3\pi)^\frac32}$$

$\large\text{Conclusion:}$

So as you can see, each integral is possible, but the mystery of the Wigner 6j symbol integral remains unsolved. A closed form is probably impossible, so how can I find a series representation of the integral in the title? A series expansion like a Taylor expansion or  [Darboux formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_formula) or [inversion formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/InversionFormulas.html) work. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: In the definition of the $6j$ symbol, there is a hypergeometric function but there is a bar on top of it. What does that mean?

Comment: @RounakSarkar That just means [divided by gamma functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric4F3/26/01/01/). The link has the definition of the regularized hypergeometric  4F3 function. Usually these types of math problems are unpopular, so thanks for the help.